# Clickable "tel:" URL for TeX resume

Tags: hyperref, urls, links, resume

I need to make my telephone number clickable. You might be familiar with this in Gmail's clickable phone numbers that dial out to your mobile phone, for example.

I'm working on my resume, and I'm using the `res` class. It looks like with what I want to do I have to make some changes to my class file, but I'm a little hesitant to do so.

Here's what I want:

*RFC 3966 compatible URL `tel:`: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966#section-5.2 (see section 5.2)

I also want it to be formatted as an "ITU-T E.123 standard telephone number": http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-E.123-200102-I/e (see section 2.4)

So basically I want:

- HTML source: "tel:15555555555"
- Typeset as: "+1 555 555 5555" (clickable of course like HTML telephone links)

My final goal is to have a clickable link for a phone number without it looking visually different, just like my email address is. It is simply clickable and it goes to my email application.

Is there a package that does `tel:`? How do I integrate this telephone solution in `res`? Does anyone ever use clickable `tel:` links in PDFs?

*edit: I Found out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164004/how-to-mark-up-phone-numbers that RFC 3966 supersedes RFC 2806.

**UPDATE**: I think I have escaped the domain of TeX with this problem. I used "You's" answer to make a clickable link that looks formatted properly. I'm just having issues with the functionality of the `tel:` standard among applications that use it. Not working: Foxit Reader, Gmail, Chrome (Windows OS). Working: Gmail mobile, mobile Quickoffice PDF viewer, Mobile dialer (Android OS).

Comment: You can try `moderncv` and use `\href` command in the Tel: part.

Comment: That is a nice idea. Are there PDF readers that know what to do with `tel:` URIs though?

Comment: Thank you percusse, I'd like to stick with `res.cls` class though, but the `\href` part helped!

Comment: Raphink: I'm testing it now. I'm counting on the idea that they do. I'm using Foxit reader, and it doesn't seem to know what to do, except it prompts me whether I want to try to open it. I'm also going to test in Chrome, and on my mobile.

Comment: I inspected a link that works in gmail: `<a href="tel:222-333-4444" value="+1222333444" target="_blank">222-333-4444</a>` I'm not sure that the `hyperref` package deals with these properly, or the applications don't understand the way it's being given to them. My browser just opens a new tab when I try "You's" method in the answers.

Comment: Was anyone ever able to get this working? I can get the link to be "clickable" but it doesn't do anything...

Comment: Hi @StevieP I got it working, however the issue is the client computer opening the file must know what to do with "tel:" associations. In Windows you need a program that accepts the "URL:tel protocol" in your Set Associations, settings. I have it working with Skype, and in the browser it works with Google Voice. In OS X and Linux I haven't tried it but your computer needs to be able to associate the hyperlink for the tel: protocol with your phone application. This is a high order for many systems since phone apps aren't always integrated in a way where you can use the tel: protocol.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that this really depends on the program. On OS X I've got no luck in preview and chrome, but safari seems to recognize the protocol... Weird.

Comment: I just did a quick search and it looks like you can do it with this method on OS X: http://superuser.com/questions/548119/how-do-i-configure-custom-url-handlers-on-os-x

Later today I can probably test it myself too. See how it works for you.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just use `\href` from [`hyperref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref):

```
\href{tel:15555555555}{+1 555 555 5555}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm kind of curious how when I entered my email (in the `tex` file I needed no hyperref inclusion for the link to work, does this mean my pdf viewer is just awesome? I have since revised the tel and mailto links to be consistent.

Comment: @projectdp It might be the case that Skype taking over stuff.

Comment: @percusse, that shouldn't matter. They are (to my understanding) using a non-RFC standard type called: `callto:`. Maybe I just need to figure out how applications know to use `tel:`? See my recent comments in my original post.

Comment: It does not work for me. A click on the link just lunches google chrome. I have Skype installed. What should I have more?

Comment: Hello Igor, I know it's been a while but the `tel:` protocol association is defined in the Operating System. If you have Skype installed it should associate with the `tel:` protocol. If you want your system to open `tel:` protocol links in another application, simply update your association for `tel:` protocol to the desired application. You can do this in: `Control Panel > Default Programs > Associate a file type or protocol with a program`. If you're using another OS, try looking for protocol association documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If error still persists, remember to **enclose whole thing in extra curly braces**

```
{\href{tel:+1XXXXXXXXXX}{+1 XXX XXX XXXX}}
```

I was getting an error so I put extra curly braces. Here is the resume header

```
\begin{center}
{\Huge \scshape YOUR NAME} \\ \vspace{7pt}
\small
\raisebox{-0.1\height} 
{\href{tel:+1XXXXXXXXXX}{\faPhone\ +1 XXX XXX XXXX}} ~
\href{mailto:name@mail.com}{\faEnvelope\ name@mail.com} ~ 
\vspace{-8pt}
\end{center}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).