# Skype button in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I'm writing my cv using the class `moderncv`. I would to insert a sort of link that, if clicked, it open skype in your pc and call or add me to your contacts.
I've tried these:

1. to call: `\href{skype:my_username?call}{name_surname}`
2. to add:   `\href{skype:my_username?add}{name.surname}`

In the compiled *.pdf it appears a clickable link "name_surname" but if I click on it nothing happen.

Edit: MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,colorlinks,linkcolor=true]{moderncv}        

\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={},
  pdftitle={},
  pdfsubject={},
  urlcolor=magenta,
}}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\providecommand\faSkype{{\FA\symbol{"F17E}}}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\moderncvstyle{banking}                            
\moderncvcolor{black}                                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}


\name{name}{surname}
\address{address}{city}{}%
\phone[mobile]{mynumber}                   
\email{myemail}                               
\extrainfo{\faSkype\ \href{skype:username?call}{name.surname}}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\vspace{-2\baselineskip}

\section{personal data}
\cvitem{...}

\section{education}
\cventry{}{...}{...}{...}{}{}  


\section{work}
\cventry{}{...}{...}{...}{}{}

\section{language}
\cvitem{language}{level}

\section{informatic}
\cvitem{languages}{Assembly}

\section{Hobby}
hello

\enlargethispage{1.3cm}
\vfill

\footnotesize
bye


\end{document}
```

Comment: This is similar to [Clickable "tel:" URL for TeX resume](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53522/5764), and I think you may experience similar difficulties.

Comment: See https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA99/how-do-i-add-contact-me-buttons-and-skype-uri-links-to-my-website-or-app