# Skype link in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, hyperlink, href

I am writing my CV using the `moderncv` package. I tried to add a Skype call link by using the command

```
\href{skype:frantisekdracek?call}{skype}
```

However, when I try to open this link, it opens the following directory path: `file:///C:/Users/.../Documents/cv/moderncv/examples/skype:username?call`

I tried to add an email command into my CV, `\href{skype:username?call}{skype}`, and it works fine.

Also, if I type `skype:username?call` into the browser, it opens my Skype, so I do not understand what the problem is.

Edit: It seems that this problem is only present with Chrome and Adobe Reader. Is there any way how to fix it for these two browsers?

Comment: Have a closer look to question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407832/skype-button-in-moderncv If that does not help please add an compilable tex code to your question resulting in your issue ...

Comment: Is your issue solved? How? With the given link in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

I tried `\href{skype:*username*?call}{skype}` and it works well!